# Webservice call failing in google's cloud test lab

Tags: android, google-cloud-test-lab

An apk runs just fine in my device. App internally makes a web service call in an async task to a server to fetch data. But when I upload same apk to google's cloud test lab and run Robo test for it,same web service call fails with error as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
```

Does google's cloud test lab don't support such calls or Robo tests have some limitations?

Comment: when you use the tag "robotframework", are you referring to the test framework from robotframework.org? There's nothing in your post that seems at all related to robot framework.

Comment: That's a mistake. Sorry for that. Cloud test lab terms its tests as robo tests, that got me confused I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Which port are you using to fetch the data? If you are using ports other than 80 or 443, it will not work.